# Derivative of the linear functional given by an inner product form

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $L\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $L_y(x)=\langle x,y\rangle$ for some inner product, and $DL$ be the derivative of $L$. Then which of the following is/are true?

1. $DL(u)=DL(v)\quad \forall u,v\in\mathbb{R}^n$;
2. $DL(0,\dots,0)=L$;
3. $DL(x)=\|x\|^2\quad \forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n$;
4. $DL(1,\dots,1)=0$.

Could any one help me to solve this problem? I have no Idea how to solve it

Answer (score 2):

$DL$ is defined as the best linear approximation of $L$:

$$\lim _{h \in \mathbb{R}^n, h \to 0} \frac{\|L(x + h) - L(x) - DL(h)\|}{\|h\|} = 0.$$

Being $L$ linear, it is the best linear approximation of itself as you can easily check. I hope this can help!

Comment: so, 1 and 2 are right. am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

For each fixed $y$, $DL_y = L_y$. To see this,
$$
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{|L_y(x+h) - L_y(x) - L_y(h)|}{|h|} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{|\langle x+h,y\rangle - \langle x,y \rangle - \langle h,y \rangle|}{|h|} = 0.
$$
This should help in answering the questions. This is true in general for any linear transformation. That is, if $T$ is linear, then $DT = T$.

Comment: I know that derivative of a linear map is itself, but which of the following is true?